# How to manually create EE 3 member accounts

Tags: members, registration, member-details

I have a situation where I may have to pull from another sites member list (not EE)and bring those over to my EE site for use.  It may be an excel sheet they provide or something else I recommend.

Can someone help explain what would need to be done to manually create member accounts with EE 3.5 so I can let them log on with creds they used from other site.  I'm assuming I'd have to know what tables it inserts to during registration and create entries in the database for all the related fields provided.

Comment: Do you have their current passwords in clear text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the plugin **Smart Member Pro** which was perfect for what I needed.  Very powerful plugin for importing member accounts and easy tags to display member data as well. Worth the money.

[Zeel Smart Member (Free)](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zeal-smart-members)

[Smart Member Pro (Paid)](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/smart-members-pro)

Comment: Hi there, I am developer of smart members PRO. I was just hanging around stackexchange and see your answer. I am glad it helps you. We have updated many things in our newer version to make import functionality more strong.

Answer (score 3):

You can import members via these [instructions](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/utilities/member-import.html).

As you will likely not import passwords you would need to set up a pw recovery template as well. This is simply a [forgot password](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/member/index.html#forgotten-password) function

Comment: Can you use this member import on any files such as a CSV or xls.... or does it have to be in the XML format?

Comment: Or would I use the "File Converter" first that I'm seeing in the CMS, which would take that CSV and convert it to something I would use for member import

Comment: As I'm aware, it must be XML. Can't speak for EE 3 only ever done in EE 2 but there are a few sites out there that can convert data between formats.

Comment: Does EE 3.5 allow you to use email as the login?  Not all members from the file they provided have a "nickname" so even if they clicked "forgot password" for the first time using their manually made account there would be no "username" to match the password.

I'm looking into an Add-On like https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zeal-smart-members which allows for emails to be used for login.  Just wasn't sure if EE 3.5 had this functionality yet.  i didn't see it in the members area of the cms

Comment: I dont believe it does but with that add-on you should be golden. I used an EE 2 module for same effect.